# Order, filter and then reorder a model query on Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I've been seaching this for hours without success.

I have a products table and  I need to take N random products from a list (of 100, from example) of best seller/top rated/most viewed products.

Using raw queries this seems to be trivial. First we take 100 high valorated products, then we reorder and finally take 3 of them.

```
select * from (select * from `products` order by `valoration` desc limit 100) as products order by RAND() limit 3;
```

This can be done using DB:table, but I need to do the same query not using raw queries. This is because my Product model has many custom methods and DB:table returns a list of stdObjects instead of a collection of Product models.

How can this be done without raw queries?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By memory, you can use the Illuminate\Support\Collection methods to get what you need.

```
$selectedProducts = Product::orderBy('valoration')->take(100)->get()->random(3);
```

Comment: `Eloquent\Collection` extends `Support\Collection` and thus has all it's methods. So there is no need for `collect()`.

Comment: It does extend `Support\Collection`, but I have stumbled on different method behaviors in the past, so this is why I give a second option in case the first doesn't work.

Comment: Ok, i got your point. In this case the function [random()](https://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Collection.html#method_random) is not overridden ([Eloquent\Collection on github](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4.2/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Collection.php))

Comment: Indeed! Also tested it with another model. First solution works, will remove workaround...

Answer (score 0):

To get a collection of model obects from a raw query you can use `hydrateRaw()`

```
$products = Product::hydrateRaw("
    select * from (
        select * from `products` order by `valoration` desc limit 100
    ) as products 
    order by RAND() limit 3
");
```

> `hydrateRaw(string $query, array $bindings = array(), string|null $connection = null)`
>
> Create a collection of models from a raw query.

([API](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_hydrateRaw))